# Amdgpu driver fail after install of hardinfo

Tags: boot, drivers, 20.04, radeon, amdgpu

I installed amdgpu driver from ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers couple months ago. I installed recently hardinfo tool, and after that driver fails. I uninstalled hardinfo.

My Ubuntu Version: 20.04.2 LTS

Logs from `dmesg | grep -i amdgpu`

```
[ 0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-25-generic root=UUID=fb0178b7-2fb1-470c-a3ad-358b8c5af723 ro quiet splash radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 vt.handoff=7
[ 0.039775] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-25-generic root=UUID=fb0178b7-2fb1-470c-a3ad-358b8c5af723 ro quiet splash radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 vt.handoff=7
[ 3.909140] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[ 3.909292] amdgpu: Topology: Add CPU node
[ 3.909342] fb0: switching to amdgpudrmfb from EFI VGA
[ 3.910536] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[ 3.910674] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: amdgpu: Trusted Memory Zone (TMZ) feature not supported
[ 3.928229] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: No more image in the PCI ROM
[ 3.928246] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: amdgpu: Fetched VBIOS from ROM BAR
[ 3.928249] amdgpu: ATOM BIOS: xxx-xxx-xxx
[ 3.930825] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: amdgpu: VRAM: 2048M 0x000000F400000000 - 0x000000F47FFFFFFF (2048M used)
[ 3.930829] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: amdgpu: GART: 1024M 0x000000FF00000000 - 0x000000FF3FFFFFFF
[ 3.930918] [drm] amdgpu: 2048M of VRAM memory ready
[ 3.930921] [drm] amdgpu: 3072M of GTT memory ready.
[ 3.931531] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: amdgpu: PCIE GART of 1024M enabled (table at 0x000000F400300000).
[ 3.965962] [drm] amdgpu: dpm initialized
[ 3.965998] [drm] AMDGPU Display Connectors
[ 3.966035] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for amdgpu/pitcairn_uvd.bin failed with error -2
[ 3.966038] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: amdgpu: amdgpu_uvd: Can't load firmware "amdgpu/pitcairn_uvd.bin"
[ 3.966041] [drm:amdgpu_device_ip_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* sw_init of IP block <uvd_v3_1> failed -2
[ 3.966246] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: amdgpu: amdgpu_device_ip_init failed
[ 3.966255] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: amdgpu: Fatal error during GPU init
[ 3.966394] amdgpu: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -2
```

Logs from `sudo lshw -c video`

```
*-display UNCLAIMED
description: VGA compatible controller
product: Curacao XT / Trinidad XT [Radeon R7 370 / R9 270X/370X]
vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
version: 00
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7e00000-f7e3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Logs from `lsmod | grep amd`

```
amdgpu 6053888 0
iommu_v2 24576 1 amdgpu
gpu_sched 40960 1 amdgpu
drm_ttm_helper 16384 2 amdgpu,radeon
ttm 73728 3 amdgpu,radeon,drm_ttm_helper
drm_kms_helper 237568 2 amdgpu,radeon
i2c_algo_bit 16384 2 amdgpu,radeon
drm 548864 6 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,radeon,drm_ttm_helper,ttm
```

I have no idea what can be the problem, someone can help or point me to some direction?

Comment: The problem likely comes from adding the PPA.